# Python: How to convert Numpy array item value type to array with this value?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What is the best way to convert such ndarray:

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

to the:

```
[[[1],[2],[3]], [[4],[5],[6]]]
```

just wrap each value to array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can introduce a new axis with [`np.newaxis/None`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) at the end, like so -

```
arr[...,None]
```

Sample run -

```
In [6]: arr = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])

In [7]: arr[...,None]
Out[7]: 
array([[[1],
        [2],
        [3]],

       [[4],
        [5],
        [6]]])

In [8]: arr[...,None].tolist() # To show it as a list for expected o/p format
Out[8]: [[[1], [2], [3]], [[4], [5], [6]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by recursively exploring the list of lists:

```
def wrap_values(list_of_lists):
    if isinstance(list_of_lists, list):
        return [wrap_values(el) for _,el in enumerate(list_of_lists)]
    else:
        return [list_of_lists]


xx = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
yy = wrap_values(xx)   # [[[1], [2], [3]], [[4], [5], [6]]]
```